# Is there an easy way to santize user data going into a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, sanitization

I have a simple script that takes a subject-line and return-path from STDIN (a piped email) and runs custom curl query using the subject:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Check for the sender email address and subject.
# Assign them to variables for use later.
while read -r key value; do
    case $key in
        Subject:) subject=$value;;
        Return-Path:) return_path=$value;;
    esac
done

# Run a curl query utilizing a modified version of the subject (replacing spaces with plus symbols)

curl "https://foo.com/&q="${subject// /+}"" >> foo.txt
```

My concern though is that this leaves a hole for malicious (or accidental) use of problematic subject headers like: **Subject: Test 123; rm -fr /;**

Is there an easy way to prevent this from happening?

I apologize if this is a vague question.  I'm very new to scripting so my knowledge of script hardening/sanitizing is very slim.  If there is a beginner's reference for this, please let me know.

---

UPDATE.  Here's the revised script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Check for the sender email address and subject.
# Assign them to variables for use later.
while read -r key value; do
    case $key in
        Subject:) subject="$value";;
        Return-Path:) return_path="$value";;
    esac
done

# Run a curl query utilizing a modified version of the subject (replacing spaces with plus symbols)

curl "https://foo.com/&q=\"${subject// /+}\"" >> foo.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Always use quotes. **ALWAYS**.

```
foo="$bar"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not quite sure how I can harden the script to reflect that as the URL is already using quotes. Can I leverage quotes in teh case section?

Comment: Your URL isn't using quotes. And yes, you should be using quotes in the case section.

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance.  I updated the example to include quotes but I'm still not seeing where I'm missing the quote in the url. Can you elaborate?  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Your second double quote closes the first one, leaving the parameter expansion completely unquoted.

Comment: AHHHH I think I see what you're saying.  My intention is to use the double quote in the middle as part of the url but I neglected to use escape characters. I've revised it again. Is this improved?

Comment: That will work, assuming you want the parameter value in quotes. Also, do note that there are more characters that will brek this script than just spaces (e.g. `&`, `+`, etc.).

Comment: You don't need quotes for the assignments. `foo=$bar` and `foo="$bar"` will work exactly the same.

Comment: @geirha when you say "work exactly the same" do you mean that they'll be equally protected? If not, what else can I do to lock down the script?

Comment: @MikeB, the main reason for quoting parameter expansions `$var` and command substitutions `$(cmd)` is to avoid doing word splitting and pathname expansion on the expanded result. For a string assignment, splitting things into words doesn't make sense, so it's not done.

Answer (score 1):

curl can urlencode that for you.

```
while read -r key value; do
    case $key in
        Subject:) subject=$value;;
        Return-Path:) return_path=$value;;
    esac
done

curl --get --data-urlencode "q=$subject" "https://foo.com/" >> foo.txt
```

No matter what the subject contains, it will at no point be treated as code.

Comment: Oooooh! I like this. So the --data-urlencode switch would do the work of converting space characters to something their HTML entity code equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that the currently accepted answer is wrong. As geirha pointed out, no need for quotes around assignments.

But change

```
curl "https://foo.com/&q=\"${subject// /+}\"" >> foo.txt
```

to

```
curl "https://foo.com/&q=${subject// /+}" >> foo.txt
```

There is no such thing as "apply two levels of quoting" unless of course you're running data through two shells.

Read sections 2.2.1 through 2.2.3 of the [sh spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) to get a good feeling for how quoting works. Also read 2.6.5 "Field Splitting" to understand how variables that are not in double quotes are split.

In no case <strike>is external input treated as a command</strike> can input "inject" a command, unless of course you trust it and are running it through another shell.

Comment: Just to clarify, I want the quotes to be in the actual curl command.  Does that change anything?  I thought by escaping them, they would be ignored by the shell.

Comment: Sorry, had forgotten to include your escaping, but I'm quite sure that you don't want to handle any quotes to curl, that's why I presented you the version with less quotes.